# :host background color not set, but font size increased?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mleq7) apply the following CSS to the `:host` element, or `<hello>`, the font size is increased, but the background color is not changed.  Thoughts:

```
styles: [`
 :host {
   font-size: 2rem; 
   background-color: yellow;  }`]
})
```

Comment: Add `display: block`. Custom tags are displayed inline by browser default.

Comment: Awesome -  Thanks!  do you want to add that as the answer and I'll check it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom elements are displayed inline by default in the browser. Just add `display: block`.